# Backbone.js model mixins

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If a backbone model (or collection) may or may not already exists, how do you extend or mixin?

Here's what I've tried:

```
mymodels.A = ('A' in mymodels ? mymodels.A : Backbone.Model).extend({
 /* url, initialize, parse, etc... */ 
});
```

or

```
mymodels.A = ('A' in mymodels ? mymodels.A.prototype : Backbone.Model).extend({
 /* url, initialize, parse, etc... */
});
```

or

```
mymodels.A = _.extend('A' in mymodels ? mymodels.A : Backbone.Model, {
 /* url, initialize, parse, etc... */
});
```

Thoughts?

**Edit:**

```
mymodels.A = (mymodels.A || Backbone.Model).extend({
 /* url, initialize, parse, etc... */
});
```

**Edit2:**

Took a different approach....see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This accomplished what I was trying to do....which was create model in pieces.  In the end, I create an object in pieces and pass the whole object to Backbone.Model.extend:

```
var mymodels = {};

mymodels.A = _.extend({}, mymodels.A, {
    url: "http://www.google.com"
});

mymodels.A = _.extend({}, mymodels.A, {
    initialize: function(){
        this.set('mixin', 'TRUE'); 
    }
});
mymodels.A = Backbone.Model.extend(mymodels.A);

var model = new mymodels.A({'new': 'TRUE'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
// ensure its created
mymodels.whatever = mymodels.whatever || Backbone.Model.extend({...; // create it empty if you need
// now if you want to extend do it knowing it's created
mymodels.whatever = mymodels.whatever.extend({...
```

if `mymodels.whaever` exists, then it will reassign the variable (do nothing). If it doesn't create the OR will need to evaluate the second part, the `new`, `Backbone.Model` or the expression you use to create the model (even something empty like `{}`).

Comment: Thanks @helios.  Tried that...didn't work either (see my edit above)

Comment: Well, what I tried to tell is 1) ensure it's created 2) extend it. So the (1) point is general Javascript, not Backbone. if mymodels.whatever doesn't exists, create it (as an empty Model if you need). Only then extend it :)

Comment: Thanks @helios...ended up approach the problem from a different angle (see my answer)...appreciate your help thinking it through